# Display an axis value in millions in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a chart where I am charting some very large numbers, in the millions.  My audience is unlikely to understand scientific notation, so I'm hoping to label the y axis in something like "2M" for two million for example.

Here's an example.  Showing the full value (`scales::comma`) is better than the scientific notation it defaults to, but is still a bit busy:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(as.data.frame(list(x = c(0, 200,100), y = c(7500000,10000000,2000000))), 
       aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  expand_limits( x = c(0,NA), y = c(0,NA)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma)
```

[image]

I don't want to rescale the data, since I will be including labels with the values of the individual data points as well.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think you can just manually set your `labels` & `breaks`

```r
library(ggplot2)

ylab <- c(2.5, 5.0, 7.5, 10)

ggplot(as.data.frame(list(x = c(0, 200, 100), y = c(7500000, 10000000, 2000000))), 
       aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  expand_limits(x = c(0, NA), y = c(0, NA)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = paste0(ylab, "M"),
                     breaks = 10^6 * ylab
  )
```

[image]

**Edit:** add a more generic solution

```r
# Ref: https://5harad.com/mse125/r/visualization_code.html
addUnits <- function(n) {
  labels <- ifelse(n < 1000, n,  # less than thousands
                   ifelse(n < 1e6, paste0(round(n/1e3), 'k'),  # in thousands
                          ifelse(n < 1e9, paste0(round(n/1e6), 'M'),  # in millions
                                 ifelse(n < 1e12, paste0(round(n/1e9), 'B'), # in billions
                                        ifelse(n < 1e15, paste0(round(n/1e12), 'T'), # in trillions
                                               'too big!'
                                        )))))
  return(labels)
}

ggplot(as.data.frame(list(x = c(0, 200, 100, 250, 300), 
                          y = c(500000, 1000000, 200000, 90000, 150000))), 
       aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  expand_limits(x = c(0, NA), y = c(0, NA)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = addUnits)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-10-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1.9000)</sup>

Comment: This works, if you know the data, not if you dont know what scale it will be (e.g. if you plot numbers for different Countries.)

Comment: @vinnief: you always know the scale of your data before plotting, no?

Comment: @vinnief: I'm sorry I don't follow you. What I meant was when you do the EDA, how plots look is not that important. They only matter when you generate plots for report or publication. At that stage you pretty much know every detail about your data and can adjust your plot code accordingly. Anyway, I updated my answer to include the code that I regularly use to account for more cases. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: For one single graph, manual works. But when making several plots at the same time, you need a solution that is not manual, nor convoluted and works across several size scales. Using label-number-si yields simpler code.  Especially when trying to follow regularly updated numbers e.g. of Covid-19 numbers in lots of regions, the wild swings and the need to show either per-million or absolute numbers.

Answer (score 63):

I find `scales::unit_format()` to be more readable:

```
library(dplyr)
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)

as.data.frame(
  list(x = c(0, 200, 100), 
       y = c(7500000, 10000000, 2000000))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  expand_limits(x = c(0, NA), y = c(0, NA)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = unit_format(unit = "M", scale = 1e-6))
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of changing the data  (`mutate(y = y / 10^6)`), the scale argument can be used to do conversion on the fly :
`scale_y_continuous(labels = unit_format(unit = "M", scale = 1e-6))`

Comment: Note in scales version 1.1.1 `unit_format {scales}` has been retired; `label_number {scales}` is the replacement function.

Comment: Please see above: the `unit_format()` is in the `scales` package. `label_number()` is the replacement function.

Answer (score 33):

In the scales package, the function `label_number_si()` automatically scales and labels with the best SI prefix, "K" for values ≥ 10e3, "M" for ≥ 10e6, "B" for ≥ 10e9, and "T" for ≥ 10e12.
See [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/scales/man/label_number_si.html)

So:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(as.data.frame(list(x = c(0, 200,100), y = c(7500000,10000000,2000000))), 
       aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  expand_limits(x = c(0, NA), y = c(0,NA)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::label_number_si())
```

[image]

Comment: Worth adding that `label_number_si()` is deprecated, coping directly from [here](https://scales.r-lib.org/reference/label_number_si.html)  ...... `label_number_si()` is deprecated because the previous unit didn't actually use SI units, but instead used the so called "short scale". You can now get the same results as before with `label_number(scale_cut = cut_short_scale())`, or if you want correct SI units, `label_number(scale_cut = cut_si("unit"))`

Answer (score 10):

Worth adding that function past to scales can create labels without specifying `breaks` argument. As stated in `?scale_y_continuous`, labels can take:

> One of:
>
> - NULL for no labels waiver() for the default labels computed by the    transformation object
> - A character vector giving labels (must be same    length as breaks)
> - **A function that takes the breaks as input and    returns labels as output**

Creating sample function is trivial:

```
(function(l) {paste0(round(l/1e6,1),"m")})(5e6)
"5m"
```

Hence the solution could be:

```
ggplot(as.data.frame(list(x = c(0, 200,100), y = c(7500000,10000000,2000000))), 
       aes(x = x, y = y)) +
    geom_point() +
    expand_limits( x = c(0,NA), y = c(0,NA)) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = function(l) {
        paste0(round(l/1e6,1),"m")
    })
```

There is no need to specify `breaks` argument.

[image: Results]

---

In the UK we tend to use small *m*.

Comment: Thanks for providing a solution that does not require defining breaks manually, nor to manipulate the data before passing it to ggplot(), and not even requires an additional package!

Answer (score 3):

As in many other situations when using ggplot2, I think the simplest way to do this is to manipulate the data *before* passing it to the ggplot() function. I would just create a new data column with the values in millions, like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(x = c(0, 200,100),
                 y = c(7500000,10000000,2000000)) %>% 
    mutate(y_millions = y/1e6)

ggplot(df, 
       aes(x = x, 
           y = y_millions)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    labs(y = "y (in millions)")
```

[image]

Comment: Note that OP wrote: "I don't want to rescale the data, since I will be including labels with the values of the individual data points as well."

Answer (score 0):

The **addUnits** function is great! I've been using it a lot, but I recently noticed it sometimes fails with y-axis scales that transition from thousands into millions, or millions into billions, or billions into trillions.

This is due to rounding. For instance, you may get the following values across your y-axis: (200k, 400k, 600k, 800k, 1M, 1M), where the second 1M should really be 1.2M.

I made the following adjustment, and just wanted to share in case it helps anyone else. There's probably a more elegant way to do it, but this works for me.

```
addUnits <- function(n) {
  labels <- ifelse(n < 1000, n,  # less than thousands
               ifelse(n < 1e6, paste0(round(n/1e3), 'k'),  # in thousands
                      ifelse(n < 1e9,
                             ifelse(round(n/1e6)==round(n/1e6,digits=1),
                                    paste0(round(n/1e6), 'M'),  # in millions
                                    paste0(round(n/1e6,digits=1), 'M')), # in 1.x millions
                             ifelse(n < 1e12,
                                    ifelse(round(n/1e9)==round(n/1e9,digits=1),
                                           paste0(round(n/1e9), 'B'), # in billions
                                           paste0(round(n/1e9,digits=1), 'B')), # in 1.x billions
                                    ifelse(n < 1e15,
                                           ifelse(round(n/1e12)==round(n/1e12,digits=1),
                                                  paste0(round(n/1e12), 'T'), # in trillions
                                                  paste0(round(n/1e12,digits=1), 'T')), # in 1.x trillions
                                           'too big!'
                                    )))))
 return(labels)
}
```