# Display a legend in millions in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I made a map color coded by population.  The numbers are really big, and I would like to show smaller numbers 1,2,3 (in millions) rather than 1,000,000 etc.

[image: The map I made with legend I would like to show (in millions)]

I found a solution for how to do this for the axis, but I have cleared my axis and need to do it for the legend.

[Display an axis value in millions in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52602503/display-an-axis-value-in-millions-in-ggplot)

Can someone help me find the equivalent of the code below for the legend?

```
p + scale_y_continuous(labels = unit_format(unit = "M", scale = 1e-6))
```

Comment: Do you need `scale_fill_continuous(labels = unit_format(unit = "M", scale = 1e-6))`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `gapminder` dataset as exampe data this can be achieved like so:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

gapminder::gapminder %>% 
  filter(year == 2007) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(gdpPercap, pop, color = pop)) +
  geom_point() + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::unit_format(unit = "M", scale = 1e-6)) +
  scale_color_continuous(labels = scales::unit_format(unit = "M", scale = 1e-6))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>